# Referencing Setup Custom Settings Fields in Salesforce CPQ Quote Terms

Tags: formula, cpq

I'm trying to reference a custom setting in Salesforce CPQ's quote term object, although instead of displaying what's in the field, it's just showing the formula. This is the formula {!$Setup.MBNZ_Speed_Disclaimers__c.FibreClassic__c}. Is it even possible for CPQ to reference setup fields? The reason I'm trying to do this is because we often have to update one certain part of multiple quote terms, so it would be more straight forward just to have one place to update, then have the quote terms reference that via formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only Objects which can be referenced on the standard HTML or Line Item Quote Term types are the following:

- Quote Template
- Quote
- Primary Contact (Contact field on Quote - so specific related Contact fields)
- Sales Rep (User field on Quote - so specific related User fields)

You can also reference the Company Logo by itself. Here is a link to the documentation which I've referenced: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_merge_fields.htm&type=5

I don't believe your Custom Setting can be referenced on a typical Quote Term record. You could build a custom Quote Term type which would use a Visualforce page and can pull through any content you can query/present in Apex.